# Using Coldfusion in Atom

Tags: coldfusion, dreamweaver, atom-editor, coldfusion-10

How do you use the text editor Atom to connect with Coldfusion 10? I am writing code but the Coldfusion is just coming out as pure text and not running.

When I open the same folder in Dreamweaver the CF code is actually running.

So basically the setup we have is a server that is running CF and our "work/files/folders". Then from my pc I open the file/folder that is on that server and run the code from my pc.

Dreamweaver works. Atom does not.

Is there something special you have to do to tell Atom to connect with the Coldfusion administrator or something?

Comment: why downvote i really am trying to figure out how to get it to work lol

Comment: atleast tell me im stupid and explain why!!!

Comment: I agree.  Downvoting without explaining why is cowardly.

Comment: Can you provide more information on exactly how you're trying to run your code.  Atom is a code editor.  It does not connect to a CF server nor does it run your code that I know of. Have you installed ColdFusion server on your machine?

Comment: Atom will not do, you probably want something like ColdFusion Builder for that.

Comment: Are you trying to load a page in a browser and you are seeing the code you wrote? If so, it seems you do not have your web server configured correctly to handle CFML files.

Comment: hmmm weird the code is on the server with CF if I open the folder in dreamweaver it runs if I open that same folder in atom it just shows the code I wrote

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that your expecting an outcome  you once had in Dreamweaver.

Comment: FYI: You get downvoted if you are asking questions on StackOverflow that aren't really programming questions. If you have a question about something you are programming in ColdFusion, that is a programming question...but If you have a question about how to do something specific in a Text Editor, that is not really a programming question (it's a Software question), and is better left to one of the other StackExchange sites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't used Dreamweaver in years but I recall that it could be configured with different views. One of those views allowed you to have a "live" browser view and a text editor side-by-side. As you made changes to the code you could see them immediately within Dreamweaver itself. I assume this is the functionality you are after. They called it "live view" apparently. Here is an example that I [found here](https://helpx.adobe.com/dreamweaver/using/dreamweaver-workflow-workspace.html).

[image: Dreamweaver Example]

> A. Application bar B. Document toolbar C. Document window D. Workspace switcher E. Panels F. Code View G. Status bar H. Tag selector I. Live View J. Toolbar

One of the true powers of Atom comes from the packages that have been developed for it. Most likely if you are looking for some functionality someone has created it already.  That's what I have found with using it. The packages that I have installed to work on CFML are:

- [atom-beautify](https://atom.io/packages/atom-beautify)
- [autocomplete-cfml](https://atom.io/packages/autocomplete-cfml)
- [language-cfml](https://atom.io/packages/language-cfml)

While Atom can handle static HTML files directly, it does not know how to render CFML files. It would need a CFML engine to do that. I have not used this package myself but I believe the one that will help you is the [browser-plus](https://atom.io/packages/browser-plus) package. It allows you to run a browser within Atom. From that browser you can surf to your ColdFusion server and see the pages you are working on.

[image: Browser-Plus Example]

If you are running ColdFusion locally on your computer then just edit the webroot files directly. If you are running ColdFusion on a server, then just map a drive to the server's webroot and you can edit the files from that mapped drive. After saving any changes just refresh that browser.

I should mention that browser-plus is only one option for Atom that I found. There are others. Depending on what your needs are a different one may work better for you. Here are a few more for reference but definitely do some searching and see what works for you.

- [atom-webbrowser](https://atom.io/packages/atom-webbrowser)
- [open-in-browser](https://atom.io/packages/open-in-browser)
- [web-view](https://atom.io/packages/web-view)

Comment: Ahh, totally forgot about DW's "live view" (or whatever it was called way back when) !

Comment: Ha! yes it's been a while. I only remember because I hated that option. I turned it off and just used Dreamweaver as a text editor.

Comment: Heh, I think I liked it for quick previewing of GUI type stuff (but that was back around CF6 or something). Not sure why I did not just use a browser ;-)

Comment: My vote put your reputation into the 5 digit range.  You owe me a beer.

Comment: @Miguel-F `If you are running ColdFusion on a server, then just map a drive to the server's webroot` How do you do this?

Comment: That depends on your operating system. On Windows you can do something like this - http://wikihow.com/Map-a-Network-Drive. If not Windows just Google it. There are lots of examples.